# Run .NET 2.0 console application in WiX custom action from binary table

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I am trying to run a console application written in C# .NET 2.0 in a custom action in my WiX MSI setup project like this:

```
<CustomAction Id="INSTALL_TEXT" Impersonate="yes" Return="check" Execute="immediate" BinaryKey="TextCreator.exe" ExeCommand="C:\test.txt -i"/>
<CustomAction Id="UNINSTALL_TEXT" Impersonate="yes" Return="check" Execute="immediate" BinaryKey="TextCreator.exe" ExeCommand="C:\test.txt -u"/>
<Binary Id="TextCreator.exe" SourceFile="C:\MyInstaller\Test\Tools\TextCreator.exe"/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="INSTALL_TEXT" After="InstallFiles">NOT Installed AND NOT PATCH</Custom>
  <Custom Action="UNINSTALL_TEXT" After="RemoveFiles">Installed AND REMOVE="ALL"</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

But I am always getting an error message in the log:

> MSI (s) (7C:C0) [14:03:01:026]: Note: 1: 1721 2: INSTALL_TEXT 3: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI9938.tmp 4: C:\test.txt -i
>   Error 1721. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action: INSTALL_TEXT, location: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI9938.tmp, command: C:\test.txt -i 
>   MSI (s) (7C:C0) [14:03:07:374]: Product: Text Creator Console App -- Error 1721. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action: INSTALL_TEXT, location: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI9938.tmp, command: C:\test.txt -i 
>   Action ended 14:03:07: INSTALL_TEXT. Return value 3.

I have embedded a MANIFEST in my application to run with administrative privileges:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

When I run the installer from command line where the console prompt has already been started with administrative privileges, both install and uninstall work fine! But when I start the MSI using double-click I am asked to run the installation (before progress bar continues) if I want to run with administrative privileges. Then my setup aborts with the error message as provided in the LOG above.

What leads to that problem? I am using WiX 3.5.2519.0 with MSI 2.0 in my project. My setup is running on Windows 7 Professional (x64). I have all frameworks installed from 2.0, through 3.0, 3.5 up to 4.0!

EDIT: On Windows XP with .NET Framework 2.0 installed, all works just fine!

**SOLUTION:**

```
<CustomAction Id="QtExecInstallText" Impersonate="no" Return="check" Execute="deferred" BinaryKey="TextCreator.exe" ExeCommand="C:\test.txt -i"/>
<CustomAction Id="QtExecUninstallText" Impersonate="no" Return="check" Execute="deferred" BinaryKey="TextCreator.exe" ExeCommand="C:\test.txt -u"/>
<Binary Id="TextCreator.exe" SourceFile="C:\MyInstaller\Test\Tools\TextCreator.exe"/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="QtExecInstallText" After="InstallFiles">NOT Installed AND NOT PATCH</Custom>
  <Custom Action="QtExecUninstallText" After="RemoveFiles">Installed AND REMOVE="ALL"</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

=> When linking pass -ext "%WIX%\bin\WixUtilExtension.dll" to light.exe!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way to run any EXE in an MSI installer is using *[Quiet Execution Custom Action](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm)*.

Examples of how to implement it are on the linked page. FWIW, a properly scheduled custom action (deferred with no impersonation) will already be running as system and manifest / [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) elevation won't apply. Additionally, if you can refactor your .NET EXE to be a client/server (EXE / DLL) arrangement then you can take the server class and consume it in a [Deployment Tools Foundation](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2008/5/16/deployment-tools-foundation-joins-the-wix-toolset) (DTF) custom action.

This is a much better design as it runs in process rather than out of process and can call [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) APIs such as getting CustomActionData attributes, writing to the MSI log, returning ErrorSuccess and/or publishing progress bar updates and action messages. Forking to an EXE file is a hack compared to this.